# Can I split a circuit in the middle of a 3-wire cable?

Tags: wire, rewire

I have an existing 14/3 romex that only has two standard lights on the run. I want to cut this wire, continue that run, but also I want a simple electric outlet in my basement. This is where the 14/2 would come into the picture.

I would tap into the existing 14/3, continue it, but then split off for a new outlet with the 14/2. I want to know if taking only one of the two hots is ok and continuing with two hots to the light switches. Thank you.

Please see picture.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure why you're upsizing the cable (which is fine), but be sure to never _downsize_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can splice into a 3-wire cable just as you'd splice a 2-wire cable, assuming it's not for a three-way switch or some other specialty case. Do it as you've drawn.

You'll need slack. If you don't have it, plan for either using *two* junction boxes, or splice at an existing box.

For the two-box method, mount two boxes at least 24" apart and cut the cable between. Make your splice in whichever box is most convenient and run a jumper between boxes. Obviously this means you need more /3 cable. Do not run parallel cables as a substitute, which would be illegal.

Be aware that junction boxes must remain accessible. Don't bury them in your walls or ceiling, or cover them with cabinets.

Comment: For emphasis: You need /3 cable between the 2 boxes. You _cannot_ run /2 and an extra wire. That's a code violation.

Answer (score 3):

### Can you settle for **two** outlets?

There's no such thing as a mid-cable "tap".

**Any splices must be done inside a junction box.  The box must remain accessible forever.  You need at least 6" of wire inside the junction box** - 9" is better so you have some margin for screw-ups.  Therefore aim for at least 18" of slack.

The only workable way is to have TWO boxes set at least 18" apart along the cable run.  *(or somewhere else if the length allows, e.g. two boxes 12' apart and down 5 feet)*.  Then, you add additional cable to connect the two boxes to restore the original circuit *(e.g. a 24' run that goes up 5 feet, over the 12 feet, and down the other 5 feet)*.

Again, the boxes must be accessible forever. They cannot be covered up with any building material (a cabinet with hinges and a latched door is fine. Easily lifted drop ceilings are also fine. A lift-out false back to a bookcase is *debatable* since the electrician will never find the darn thing when trying to chase a wire problem.)

It's perfectly acceptable to bring the splice box somewhere visible and just go ahead and make it a receptacle box.  You can have receptacles in weird places.  (however if they're GFCI receps that need to be TESTed and RESET sometimes, they must be sanely located).